# Can I create private enum constructors?

Tags: rust

In Haskell I could do something like this (example adapted from [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types))

```hs
module Shapes (
    Shape,
    newCircle,
    newRectangle,
    ... -- other functions for manipulating the shapes
)

data Shape = Circle Int Int Float       -- x, y, radius
           | Rectangle Int Int Int Int  -- x1, y1, x2, y2

newCircle :: Float -> Shape
newCircle r = Circle 0 0 r

newRectangle :: Int -> Int -> Shape
newRectangle w h = Rectangle 0 0 w h

... -- other functions for manipulating the shapes
```

That would allow me to only expose the `Shape` type and the `newCircle` and `newRectangle` functions.

Does Rust have an equivalent for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about checking Rust documentation and roadmap.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation and the roadmap? As a new Rust user, I haven't discovered all the documentation yet. I, as I imagine many new users do, am going through the book, and when that doesn't go into enough detail I'm left searching for answers elsewhere.

Comment: @Chiron I think the core question is a good one, the title just needed to be tweaked a bit to be a concrete question (like the body is), not a future plans question.

Comment: @njpaul the [documentation index](http://doc.rust-lang.org/) links to the [Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), the [Reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html) and the [standard library](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/). Bigger future plans are generally found in the [RFCs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs).

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the links. I found the first three pretty easily from the website, but didn't know about the RFCs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a general sense, no; Rust does not have private enum constructors. Enums are purely public things.

Structs, however, are not like that, and so you can combine them to make the variants purely an implementation detail:

```
// This type isn’t made public anywhere, so it’s hidden.
enum ShapeInner {
    // Oh, and let’s use struct variants ’cos they’re cool.
    Circle {
        x: i32,
        y: i32,
        radius: f64,
    },
    Rectangle {
        x1: i32,
        y1: i32,
        x2: i32,
        y2: i32,
    },
}

// Struct fields are private by default, so this is hidden.
pub struct Shape(ShapeInner);

impl Shape {
    pub fn new_circle(radius: f64) -> Shape {
        Shape(Circle { x: 0, y: 0, radius: radius })
    }

    pub fn new_rectangle(width: i32, height: i32) -> Shape {
        Shape(Rectangle { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: width, y2: height })
    }

    // “match self.0 { Circle { .. } => …, … }”, &c.
}
```

I would advise against this as a general practice, however.

Comment: why would you advise against that? Because it looks a lot like a design pattern?

Comment: @ker: there is no inherent evil in “design patterns”. It is merely that this is not in general going to be idiomatic Rust, though there may be certain cases that are well suited for this (I can’t think of any off-hand to give examples, though).

Comment: [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/error.rs.html#58-75) uses this pattern.

Comment: Good answer, except for the "advise against this" sentence.